# Syntax for checking multiple conditions in an 'if' statement

Tags: c#

This is situation:

```
if count items is either 0,1,5,7,8,9,10 then string = "string one"
if count items is either 2,3,4 then string = "string two"
```

I tried with (inside cs razor view)

```
@if (@item.TotalImages == 1 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 10)
{
   string mystring = "string one"
}
```

but I'm getting this error

> operator || cannot be applied to operands of type bool or int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or perhaps

```
var accepted = new HashSet<int>(new[] {1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10});

@if (accepted.Contains(item.TotalImages))
{
   string mystring = "string one"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have wrong syntax for **[or operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.

Change to.

```
@if (@item.TotalImages == 1 || @item.TotalImages == 5)
{
   string mystring = "string one"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `In` extension method could be a syntactic sugar for a situation like this:

```
public static class CLRExtensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
    {
        return list.Contains(source);
    }
}
```

So basically instead of using multiple `or operator`, you could simply write:

```
@if (@item.TotalImages.In(1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10)
{
}
```

Comment: nice usage of generics for this application.

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look at the error message:

> operator || cannot be applied to operands of type **bool** or **int**

And your code:

```
@if (@item.TotalImages == 1 || 5)
```

You're applying the || operator to a bool (@item.TotalImages == 1) and an int (5).  'True or 5' doesn't make sense.  Neither does 'False or 5'

Basically, all you need to do is make both sides of the || operator booleans.

```
@if (@item.TotalImages == 1 || @item.TotalImages == 5)
```

There are (of course) lots of other clever ways to do this, but that's probably the most straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You may end up with a very big 'if' statement if you want to check all those possibilities. A terser way to do it using LINQ would be:

```
@if ((new List<int>{ 0, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 }).Contains(@item.TotalImages))
{
    string mystring = "string one"
}
```

This way you can more easily see and maintain the list of numbers to check against (or, indeed pass them in from somewhere else).

Comment: The "Contains" method of `HashSet<T>` is more efficient than that of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a switch:

```
@switch (@item.TotalImages)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        s = "string one";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        s = "string two";
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unexpected image count");
}
```

Oddly, nobody has suggested a dictionary:

```
private string stringOne = "string one";
private string stringTwo = "string two";

private Dictionary<int, string> _map = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 0, stringOne },
    { 1, stringOne },
    { 2, stringTwo },
    { 3, stringTwo },
    { 4, stringTwo },
    { 5, stringOne },
    { 7, stringOne },
    { 8, stringOne },
    { 9, stringOne },
    { 10, stringOne },
}
```

then

```
@var s = _map[@item.TotalImages];
```

This approach makes it easier to see, for example, that you have not handled the case where TotalImages == 6.

Comment: Why would you favour a switch statement as opposed to the other solutions proposed? Just interested...

Comment: @Holf on the assumption that the compiler can do it more efficiently than I can.  Also, some other answers mentioned maintainability.  If the logic is subject to change, then I'd be more inclined to use a `Dictionary<int, string>` as it would be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Between "||" always must be an expression, that can be transleted to Boolean (true / false):

```
@if (@item.TotalImages == 1 || @item.TotalImages == 5 || @item.TotalImages == 7 || @item.TotalImages == 8 || @item.TotalImages == 9 || @item.TotalImages == 10)
    {
       string mystring = "string one"
    }
@else @if(@item.TotalImages == 2 || @item.TotalImages == 3 || @item.TotalImages == 4)
    {
       string mystirng = "string two"
    }
```